# Как сделать просмотр фотографии, как в ВК

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать просмотр фотографии, как в ВК? В Вк когда нажимаешь на картинку, экран замораживается и скролл, который был ранее для просмотра ленты стал скроллить только изображение если оно не помещается на экране

Comment: Почитайте о модальных окнах на [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Модальное_окно) и советую вот эту [замечательную статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148515/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Так ведь куча всяких надстроек... вот например [highslide](*ссылка удалена, так как ведет либо на странный редирект, либо на сообщение о том, что домен просрочен*), один из популярных. если вообще как вконтакте, то модальные окна смотрите... опять же, все равно придется допиливать

Comment: Зашел, чтобы предложить highslide.. Не успел)